# How to count the rows of a column grouping by a column but omitting the others columns of the table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, count, grouping

I want to do a count grouping by the first column but omitting the others columns in the group by. Let me explain:

I have a table with those columns

[image]

So, what I want to get is a new column with the work orders total by Instrument, something like this:

[image]

How can I do that? Because if I do a count like this:

SELECT INSTRUMENT, WORKORDER, DATE, COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY INSTRUMENT, WORKORDER, DATE;

I get this:

[image]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a window function:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by instrument) as instrument_count
from table1 t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although answer given by Gordon is perfect but there is also another option by using group by and subquery. You can add date column to this query as well

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT A.INSTRUMENT, B.TOTAL_COUNT_BY_INSTRUMENT  
FROM work_order A, 
(SELECT COUNT(1) AS TOTAL_COUNT_BY_INSTRUMENT, 
INSTRUMENT
FROM WORK_ORDER 
GROUP BY INSTRUMENT
) B
WHERE A.INSTRUMENT = B.instrument);
```